# How can i change method's parameter value by using another method in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Just in case,i want to change **send_timed_messages** method's which is **time**.Whenever I try to run this code(btw this is not all of the code),i get an error which says **"TypeError: change_interval() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"**.I can not change **time** parameter's value by using another method which is **change_interval** .How can i change it?

PS:If you could,can you tell me how can i change **count** parameter as well?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import os

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True,presences=True, guild_messages=True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def send_timed_msg(ctx,*args):
    text = ""
    for x in args:
        text = text + " " + x
    await send_timed_messages.start(text)

@client.command()
async def change_interval(*, minutes= 0):
    
    send_timed_messages.change_interval(float(minutes))

@tasks.loop(minutes= 0.06,count= 2) 
async def send_timed_messages(msg,time=0,count=0): #Parameter that I want to change if needed
    for x in client.get_all_channels():
        if x.id == 886984276342620170: #This id is a channel's id which I want to send this message
            await x.send(msg)

client.run(Mytoken)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. i recommend you [read the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval)

2. `change_interval` only takes keyword arguments, in this case you should be passing `minutes=minutes`.